# Instagram ajax call loop with pagination

Tags: jquery, pagination, instagram

I need to retrieve 12 images from the Instagram feed which works fine using the code below. The problem is that the results returned are for all images that have been liked (by our account) and have a specific tag. Due to the pagination of results, I won't always have the 12 images in the first response. I need to keep calling the API using the pagination 'next_url' until I have 12 images that fit the conditions.

How would I keep doing this in a loop modifying the code I have to get my 12 images?

```
var e = 0;

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked/?count=20&access_token=[token_value]",
    success: function (t) {
        var count = t.data.length;
        for (var n = 0; n < count; n++) {
            var r = t.data[n].tags;
            var tagcount = t.data[n].tags.length;
                for (y = 0; y <= tagcount; y++) {
                    if (e < 12) {
                        if (r[y] === "MyTagToFind") {
                            $("#instafeed").append(" <a target='_blank' href='" + t.data[n].link + "'><img class='instagram-image' src='" + t.data[n].images.low_resolution.url + "' /></a> ");
                            e++
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: whats wrong in current code ?

Comment: @dreamweiver It only does the one call, I'm going to need to do multiple calls. After the first call, I would need to call the next_url supplied in the current response.

Comment: Enclose your complete ajax call in a function and call this function after your looping statement based on whether you have reached your 12 images limit or not , else return.